Nav2 Voxel Layer Costmap Issue: Path Planner Ignores Obstacles from PointCloud Data
Hello Robotics Stack Exchange community,
I'm experiencing an issue with the Nav2 voxel layer when using point cloud data to update my local costmap in ROS2. The costmap appears to be updated correctly with obstacles detected from the point cloud, but the generated path doesn't seem to avoid these obstacles. Instead, the path goes right through them.
Overview of My Setup:
AMCL is being used for localization.

The local_costmap and global_costmap are set up with both voxel_layer
and obstacle_layer.
The voxel_layer plugin is enabled and configured
to use a point cloud source from an Intel RealSense camera (topic:
/intel_realsense1/points).
The obstacle_layer is configured to use
laser scan data from a lidar sensor (topic: /scan/top).

My Issue:

The local costmap is updated using the voxel layer with point cloud
data. The voxel layer appears to work correctly in marking obstacles
in the local costmap.

However, when the path planner generates a path, it does not avoid
these obstacles marked by the voxel layer. The path often goes
straight through the detected obstacles.


Configuration Snippet:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 12.0
    laser_min_range: -0.1
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 120
    max_particles: 10000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.05
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: /scan/top

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.25
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.5
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.2
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 1.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 1.2
      decel_lim_x: -1.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -1.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.5
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.5
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      sensor_frame: lidar_center_link_1
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 0.22
      footprint: '[ [0.35, 0.35], [-0.35, 0.35], [-0.35, -0.35], [0.35, -0.35] ]'
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]

      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 5.0
        inflation_radius: 3.0

      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 3.0
        mark_threshold: 2
        combination_method: 1
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:  
          topic: /intel_realsense1/points
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"

      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan/top
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True 
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
# 
        
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True

      always_send_full_costmap: True

  local_costmap_client:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False

  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 0.22
      footprint: '[ [0.35, 0.35], [-0.35, 0.35], [-0.35, -0.35], [0.35, -0.35] ]'
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "voxel_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan/top
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True 
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0

      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: False
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 3.0
        mark_threshold: 3
        combination_method: 1
        observation_sources: pointcloud
        pointcloud:   
          topic: /intel_realsense1/points
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          min_obstacle_height: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"

      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.5
      always_send_full_costmap: True
    
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: map.yaml

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 14.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.5
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [1.5, 0.0, 1.2]
    max_decel: [-1.5, 0.0, -1.2]
    odom_topic: /odom
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

EDIT: have added images showing the path generation issue as requested. I have also tried different configurations for the layers. For example, I tried using only the voxel layer for my local costmap with two sources: scan and pointcloud. Unfortunately, the issue persists.

Obstacle that can be detected by lidar

Path generated is good which avoids the obstacle

Smaller obstacle not in range of lidar

Path generated over the obstacle but costmap is updated correctly

You didn't show us anything to do with your path or problem. Please update your question with more information / pictures / what you tried.

@SteveMacenski I have tried different configs but still facing the same issue do you think this is a problem with DDS?

Was that plan generated while the obstacle was in that position? Are you visualizing the global costmap? What version of Nav2 are you using?

Yes plan was generated after I places the obstacle. I am using nav2 default view with voxel marker visualization. I am using the nav2 that comes with humble from apt.
